# Locking stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have a stored procedure with a select and an update. I would like to prevent multiple users, from executing it, at the same time, so I don't update, based on an incorrect select.
How do I lock it?
I've read various solutions (Transaction isolation, xlock), but I haven't been able to figure what I really want, and how to do it.

Comment: Can you add the UPDATE and SELECT commands please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to forget about data locks but look at [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) to control access through the code

```
BEGIN TRY

   EXEC sp_getapplock ...

   SELECT ...

   UPDATE ...

   EXEC sp_releaseapplock 

END TRY
...
```

Saying that, with thing like the OUTPUT clause and judicious use of ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK there is a good chance the UPDATE and SELECT can be one statement

Answer (score 0):

Using the [XLOCK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) table hint in the `SELECT` query:

```
CREATE TABLE [X]([x] INT NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT [X]([x]) SELECT 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [ATOMIC]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @x INT = (
        SELECT [x]
        FROM [X] (XLOCK)
    ) + 1

    UPDATE [X] SET [x] = @x

    COMMIT TRAN
END
GO
```

You can then test this by running

```
EXEC [ATOMIC]
GO 10000
```

simultaneously from different sessions.  You can test using

```
SELECT [x] FROM [X]
```

The value should be exactly 10 000 times the number of sessions you ran.  If the number is less than expected you don't have atomic read + write, or some SPIDs may have been killed due to dead locking.